# Ask haskell stack to list available versions of a package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there a way to list available versions of a given package from stack? For instance today if I run `stack install tidal` and then `stack list-dependencies` I see that tidal-0.1.0.0 was installed. I want to know if there are older versions of this package available. Relatedly where is the repo that stack points to for packages? Is it the same place cabal retrieves from?

Comment: One of the *main points* of `stack` is that it pins all packages to a *single, precise* version, based on your current resolver. You can see the different resolvers on [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org), which is the separate-but-related system that manages nightly and LTS snapshots. The snapshots are simply one-to-one package → version mappings, and they do not actually store the packages themselves. Packages are stored on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org), the same place `cabal-install` downloads packages from, and you can see all the versions of any package there.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, that helped me know where to look for a better grasp of stack. Would you have any idea why stack would still be installing tidal-0.1.0.0 after doing stack new --resolver nightly-2017-05-16 tidal, cd tidal, stack update, stack setup, stack install tidal? When I look under that nightly resolver on stackage, it contains tidal-0.9.4 which is the one I need.

Comment: It’s a little unclear to me what you’re trying to do. Are you trying to install `tidal` as a library? Or are you trying to install a `tidal` binary and copy it somewhere into your `PATH`, somewhere outside of a Haskell project? I’m not familiar with `tidal` itself, but the two use-cases are very different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm trying to install it as a library in a project, because where I'm running into trouble is when installing in the same project stack install tidal-midi which gives me a dependency error that tidal-0.1.0.0 must match >=0.9.4. All the instructions I've seen just use cabal install tidal, cabal install tidal-midi, but being new to Haskell I was under the impression that I should try and use stack instead of cabal to avoid dependency issues. This is probably the point where I should start reading some manuals since you asking for clarification leaves me a bit stumped.

Comment: If that’s the case, you almost certainly don’t want `stack install`. The `stack install` command is, in my opinion, poorly named, and it comes from the same tradition of `make install` meaning “copy a binary into my `PATH`”, which is pretty gross. I would rather tools *not* copy binaries all over my filesystem, thank you very much. What you probably want is to add `tidal` and `tidal-midi` to the `build-depends` section of your `.cabal` file, then run `stack build` (or `stack build --file-watch` if you want automatic recompilation), and `stack` should figure out what to properly install.